# Pretty Date 'weeks ago' not working properly

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm using the below code to make a readable time in relation to now. It works fine until it needs to print the 'weeks ago' code then Sinatra spits up: "undefined method `/' for "15":String"

```
def pretty_date(stamp)
  now = Time.new
  diff = now - stamp
  day_diff = ((now - stamp) / 86400).floor

  day_diff == 0 && (
    diff < 60 && "just now" ||
    diff < 120 && "1 minute ago" ||
    diff < 3600 && (diff / 60).floor.to_s + " minutes ago" ||
    diff < 7200 && "1 hour ago" ||
    diff < 86400 && (diff/3600).floor.to_s + " hours ago") ||
  day_diff == 1 && "Yesterday" ||
  day_diff < 7 && day_diff.to_s + " days ago" ||
  day_diff < 31 && (day_diff.to_s / 7).ceil + " weeks ago";
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are doing the following

```
day_diff.to_s / 7
```

You can't divide a string. Just do:

```
day_diff / 7
```